# How to group a series of numbers in oracle sql, with a specific number provided

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a series of numbers stored in an oracle table in the following format.

```
Emp_ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
14
15
16
17
18
31
32
33
34
35
36
41
42
```

I want to group this list by a fixed number like 7 and get the output in the following format:

```
Range         Total
1-7            7
8-10,14-17     7
18-18,31-36    7
41-42          2
```

Comment: Guess GROUP BY ROW_NUMBER()/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the range representation as shown in your example:

```
-- test data
with data(empid) as
 ( -- complete list 1..42
  select level
    from dual
  connect by level <= 42
  minus (
         -- minus gaps
         select level
           from dual
          where level between 11 and 13
         connect by level <= 42
         union
         select level
           from dual
          where level between 19 and 30
         connect by level <= 42
         union
         select level
           from dual
          where level between 37 and 40
         connect by level <= 42))

-- select:  
select listagg(case
                 when minempid = maxempid then
                  minempid || ' '
                 else
                  (minempid || '-' || maxempid)
               end,
               ', ') within group(order by minempid),
       sum(cnt)
  from (select grp,
               seq,
               min(empid) as minempid,
               max(empid) as maxempid,
               count(*) cnt
          from (select empid, rn, empid - rn as seq, ceil(rn / 7) as grp
                  from (select empid, row_number() over(order by empid) rn
                          from data))
         group by grp, seq)
 group by grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g you could use `listagg()` and analytic functions:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8522e/1)</sup>

```
with t1 as (
    select emp_id id,row_number() over (order by emp_id) rn from test),
  t2 as (
    select id, rn, floor((rn-.1)/7) grp,
           min(id) over (partition by floor((rn-.1)/7), id-rn)||'-'||
           max(id) over (partition by floor((rn-.1)/7), id-rn) rng
      from t1),
  t3 as (select grp, rng, min(rn) rn, count(1) cnt from t2 group by grp, rng)
select listagg(rng, ', ') within group (order by rn) range, sum(cnt) total
  from t3 group by grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be to determine the range of each value using case and the grouping on that range:

```
select rng, count(1) from (
  select 
    case  
      when emp_id between 1 and 7 then 'range 1'
      when emp_id between 8 and 10 or emp_id between 14 and 17 then 'range 2'
      when emp_id between 18 and 18 or  emp_id between 31 and 36 then 'range 3'
      when emp_id between 41 and 42 then 'range 4'
      else 'no range'
    end as rng
  from employees) 
group by rng;
```